# He suggested that our team have a meeting vs. he suggested that our team has a meeting

Tags: grammar, differences, sentence

My team's boss suggested that our team should have a meeting with another team. We are currently trying to write a message to the other team but cannot come to a conclusion as to how to write a particular sentence.

Here are the two sentences we are torn between

> Our boss suggested that our team have a meeting with your team.

and

> Our boss suggested that our team has a meeting with your team.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I found this. https://proofreading.ie/portfolio/using-have-and-has-correctly/

Comment: I'd use alternative wording entirely; "Our boss has suggested our teams meet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Have" is the subjunctive form, and is appropriate to discuss something that is being proposed. "Has" is indicative, and is appropriate to discuss something that definitely is true. So if you're using "suggest" in the sense of "propose", "have" is the correct form.